# Penalty for flagging questions/answers

Tags: discussion, review, flags, code-formatting, low-quality-posts

First of all let's read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators):

> If you see anything in the system that is evil, weird, or in any way
>   exceptional and deserving of moderator attention for any reason…flag
>   it! That’s the primary job of a moderator: to look at every flagged
>   post, and take action if necessary.

**My problem (penalty).** 
Then I flagged an answer as "low quality", I get the ban for a month. As for me, when I see the answer/question on Stack Overflow without code examples or without formatting - it is low quality or off-topic. Stack Overflow is about code and code problems, there is no place here for discussion "I push the button and was something strange".

I failed on this question: [ITC.apps.validation.pre release build missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892686/itc-apps-validation-pre-release-build-missing).

And I don't understand why @bender answer is not "low quality".

p.s., It was my 3-4 fail today, but I was reviewed ~ 100-120 questions/answers and was also was successful on 4-5 tests. May be problem in this? But I still think that marked answer is low quality. And that month is too much.

p.p.s., One of my answers [addEventListener on custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835768/addeventlistener-on-custom-object/21006231#21006231) and one of my questions [HTML file input control with capture and accept attributes works wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong). This is quality.

p.p.p.s., My flag statistics:

```
618 moderator attention flags
5   waiting for review
472 deemed helpful
10  declined
131 disputed
```

I just think that my flagging should be free from the ban.

Comment: If you mean the "I've had the same issue but I've tried ... and it seems to work" answer - yeah, that is an answer. Pretty useful one it seems, based on the upvotes.

Comment: What did you want to flag it as?

Comment: The "I've had the same issue but I've tried ... and it seems to work" answer is off-topic and that the problem can't be reproduces.

Comment: How is that answer off-topic? If it's just incorrect, downvote.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your post, partially because your examples for "high quality posts" leads back to __your own__ posts (and doesn't really have high scores to begin with). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25511635/3622940) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25298139/3622940) (disclosure: my posts) I would say features more detailed explanations as answers, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/3622940) currently highest scored [so] question deserves the "This is quality." banner more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I flagged an answer as low quality, I get the ban for the month

Assuming that you were banned from flagging/review for a month (as opposed to any other form of banning), this probably means you should look at how you flag posts and find alternatives to flagging/reviewing.

> I see the answer/question on Stack Overflow without code examples or without formatting - it is low quality or off-topic

Not automatically so, no.

And if you see a post that is lacking formatting? Suggest an edit to improve the formatting - that's much more constructive.

If you see an answer that doesn't contain code - well... not all answers need to have code in order to be useful or actually answer the question.

---

As a side note:

> deserving of moderator attention

Means - really, really, really horrible. Something that needs a human being with mod powers to look at.

If the issue is something that can be dealt with by the community (voting to close, delete, edits, community flags and such), then it is not something deserving of moderator attention (in particular - be careful of using the "other" flag reason).

The moderators, particularly on the larger sites, are busy - they have lots to do and using moderator flags for stuff that can be handled by the community is a misuse of their time.

Comment: The answer doesn't even need code samples.

Comment: "flagging stuff that can be handled by the community is a misuse of their time." - I assume you mean "other" flags?  Most flags are handled by the community

Comment: @Jan - mostly "other" flags, true, but not only.

Comment: I was understanding `moderator attention` with `low quality` as `low quality` review group. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that statement is misleading. Using mod-flags where community flags would have sufficed is a misuse. Flagging spam as spam, closeworthy questions for closure.. all of that is welcome but your answer makes it sound like it's not.

Comment: @Pinal the real issue is that the answer isn't very low quality. Minor formatting fixups should be handled by suggesting an edit. VLQ = "should be deleted ASAP"

Comment: @Jan - better? Please feel free to edit the post.

Comment: I am flagging this answer as very low quality because I feel like it.